# Calling two onclick functions

Tags: php, javascript, onclick

I have a submit button with onclick="return loadSubmit()" and i want to hide it after clicking with this this.style.visibility = "hidden";

i tried to make these two functions in the same button

```
<input type="image" name="Generate" class="contSubmit" src="generate.png" onclick='return loadSubmit();this.style.visibility = "hidden";'  />
```

but this does not work, what's the solution please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are going to change the visibility no matter what the result of `loadSubmit` is, just swap the statements around so the return statement is last.

```
onclick='this.style.visibility = "hidden";return loadSubmit();'
```

Answer (score 4):

Just swap them order

```
 onclick='this.style.visibility = "hidden"; return loadSubmit();'
```